# Odoo 8 - Add button in invoice supplier form

Tags: inheritance, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-view

I try to add as the documentation says and when I update the module it doesn't work.

```xml
<record id="some_example_id" model="ir.ui.view"> 
    <field name="name">example.name</field> 
    <field name="model">account.invoice</field> 
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_supplier_form" /> 
    <field name="arch" type="xml"> 
        <data> 
            <button name="invoice_cancel" position="after"> 
                <button name="test_button" states="draft,proforma2,open" string="test" groups="base.group_no_one" class="oe_highlight"/>
             </button> 
        </data> 
    </field> 
</record>
```

[Exactly here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogS7v.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems good to me. You may try with following tips.

- Make sure xml file name given in manifest file.
- Active debugger mode.
- Temporary remove *groups="base.group_no_one"* from button and upgrade your module.

Just for a note:

Your button will call workflow because you didn't give *type* attribute to button. If you want to call python function directly then we need to add attribute in button like

```
type="object"
```

Comment: make sure you have installed module. Sometime we try code but forgot to install module. That's happen me many times.

Answer (score 0):

use xpath expression to target and put you elements.

```xml
    <record id="some_example_id" model="ir.ui.view"> 
        <field name="name">example.name</field> 
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field> 
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_supplier_form" /> 
        <field name="arch" type="xml"> 
                <!-- using xpath target the element that you want to put button inside
                     or after or before ex: header -->  
                <xpath expr="//header" position="inside">
                    <button name="test_button" states="draft,proforma2,open" string="test" groups="base.group_no_one" class="oe_highlight"/>
                </xpath>
        </field> 
    </record>
```

Comment: ok i think you are missing some thing what i suggest is to make a syntax error like make `<field`  or `<field1` and see if you have an error

Comment: and remove the group first when you see the button than add it because if your user don't have this group the button will not be shown

Answer (score 0):

Just remove group from that button then button will be visible.

```xml
<button name="invoice_cancel" position="after"> 
    <button name="test_button" states="draft,proforma2,open" string="test" class="oe_highlight"/>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add your xml file to the Odoo module manifest file `__openerp__.py` or for newer version `__manifest__.py` under `data` like

```py
{
    'author': 'me',
    'name': 'My Module',
    'depends': [base],
    # and so on
    'data': [
        'my/path/to/my/views.xml',
        'views/account_invoice_views.xml'  # as in the odoo guideline
    ]
}
```